# Two webpages displaying differently special spanish characters

Tags: php, html, mysql, special-characters

I have a website where the web pages feed from the same database and I found that in two webpages that have same queries they interpretate the spanish special characters differently.

I cant really figure out what is wrong as I have stripped out the code which is interpreting the special spanish characters wrong and building it up from the scratch.

This one interpretes the characters well.
http://amragl.com/

This one interpretes the characters wrong.
http://amragl.com/menu.php

They both have the following

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

They both feed from the same database and use same queries.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

--UPDATE-
PEASE SEE THE WORD "GAZPACH" or "AL LIM" to see the difference.

Comment: Can you point out specifically where this issue is at?  I looked at `€` and it seems the same in both on FireFox 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

in the same file.

I suggest only using the utf-8 one.

Comment: Humm... Nice catch, I didn't saw that before. =O

Comment: Weirdly, so does http://amragl.com/index.php and `GAZPACHÓ` shows correctly there.

Comment: true, its on both pages, but different display.

Comment: Thank You!!!! this was it, I had those two lines on both pages, but I dont understand why it was displaying differently. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes thats strange. i checked the encoding with chrome and they were different for both pages for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Change `iso-8859-1` to `utf-8`, *should* fix it.

The `menu.php` page is rendering with `windows-1252` encoding, even tho it has `iso-8859-1` set.

Are the `menu.php` contents coming from a database? If yes, which encoding is the database using?